# Redisplay the splash screen on a button click in 2nd form

Tags: c#, forms, dialog, hidden, splash-screen

```
//Splash form:
//------------

frmMain main = new frmMain();
this.Hide();
main.Show();

//MainForm:
//---------
var formToShow = (frmSplash)System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().FirstOrDefault(c => c is frmSplash);

formToShow.Show();      
//formToShow.ShowDialog() execute the load event which I dont want.
formToShow.RunTestMetod()

//How I can get the splash hidden form without loading its Load Event and running its //TestMethod(). I want the mainform under it not accessible same like a message box dialog.
```

I dont want formtoShow.topmost = true as that keep it on the top but the 2nd form is still clickable. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use ShowDialog() instead.

Comment: formToShow.Show(this); let me click on the frmMain which I dont want. After showing, I just want form frmSplash on the top while frmMain under it unclickable.

Comment: .ShowDialog() run the load event of frmSplsh which I dont want

Answer (score 0):

You can use `myNewForm.Show(this);` for the Window you want to be shown as a dialog. This will show `myNewForm` as a child of the current form, but lets you interact with the current form.

Answer (score 0):

You could just **disable** MainForm?

```
// ...
    var formToShow = (frmSplash)System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().FirstOrDefault(c => c is frmSplash);
    this.Enabled = false;
    formToShow.FormClosed += frm_FormClosed;
    formToShow.Show(this);      
    formToShow.RunTestMetod()

void frm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Enabled = true;
}
```